# dosent work group by with where con dintion query in android

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by, where-clause

i try to two difrent table data combine in single query by using where condition and group by ,but cant work this query.

```
cur=dh.rawQuery("select _milkid,milkType,milkLitre,totalAmount from MilkDetail where milkDate='"+reportDate+"'" GROUP BY milkType, null);
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question, it is difficult to understand what you are asking. I see no syntax errors with this query.

Comment: `GROUP BY milkType` should be inside the "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is malformed, GROUP BY milktype is out of the sql syntax

```
cur=dh.rawQuery("select _milkid, milkType, milkLitre, totalAmount from MilkDetail where milkDate='" + reportDate + "' GROUP BY milkType", null);
```